# find earliest date for two different strings in the same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of data containing work order states, and another column indicating the date the work order is scheduled to finish. I need to work out the earliest date for a work order with a state of 'WCON' or ACK'

I use this formula

```
=SMALL(IF(OR('Raw PM Data'!$E$2:$E$999="WCON")*('Raw PM Data'!$E$2:$E$999="ACK"),'Raw PM Data'!$L$2:$L$999),1)
```

Column E has the states and column L has the date.

It works fine if the data set has both a ACK and WCON entry, however if the data set has no 'ACK', the formula breaks and '!NUM' is reported.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to resolve the problem

Thanks

Garry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a + instead of the `OR`.  Array formulas do not like `OR` or `AND` qualifiers:

```
=SMALL(IF(('Raw PM Data'!$E$2:$E$999="WCON")+('Raw PM Data'!$E$2:$E$999="ACK"),'Raw PM Data'!$L$2:$L$999),1)
```

This is an Array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

This works in that any row that has "WCON" or "ACK" will return true; > 0.  Those rows will be then used to find the smallest. One will be zero and the other 1.  So adding them together you get 1.  If neither it would return 0.

Since you are finding the first smallest you could also use MIN:

```
=MIN(IF(('Raw PM Data'!$E$2:$E$999="WCON")+('Raw PM Data'!$E$2:$E$999="ACK"),'Raw PM Data'!$L$2:$L$999))
```

Use the `*` or ultiple IF statements when wanting the `AND` qualifier.

Just to show it works:

[image]

Comment: The last statement using Min and '+' worked atreat in this instance. Thanks Scott.

Comment: @user3556622 glad I could help, please consider marking as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to implement as per below. Added new column with maximum possible date (eg: `31/12/9999` i specified in `F2`).

I then used formula `M2=IF(OR(E2="WCON",E2="ACK"),L2,$F$2)` and then dragged this formula till M999 ie., `M999=IF(OR(E999="WCON",E999="ACK"),L999,$F$2)`. I then used formula `=SMALL(M2:M999,1)` to get the minimum value.

[Formula in M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhjOK.jpg)

[Formula in O2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlUgO.jpg)

[Scott Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GMJG.jpg) - This answer is correct. Press `ctrl+shift+enter`.

Edit: Removed screenshot about Scott answer. His answer is correct.

Comment: You can also do `=IF(SMALL(M2:M999,1)=F2,"NO MATCH",SMALL(M2:M999,1))` to avoid display `31/12/9999` if nothing matches

Comment: Thanks Abdul, i'll try some more data to see if Scott's suggestion breaks. The data set I'm using is an import from a service system and the formulas are on a separate worksheet away from the raw data. So adding columns is not ideal. Thx

Comment: You still should put the pictures in the answer directly.  In the edit mode there is a button that looks like a mountain.  It will allow you to paste the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a complex formula in cell, I've created a public function with the use of visual basic, which can be used as a personalized worksheet function.

First bring up the VB Editor by pressing "alt-F11", that should bring up a window like this:

[image: VB editor]

In this window you'll have to add a module, by clicking insert and then module, which should result in an empty code module, in there you can past the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function SMALLIF(Criteria1 As Variant, Criteria2 As Variant, CriteriaRange As Range, DataRange As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrDat() As Variant
    Dim arrRes() As Variant
    ReDim arrRes(0)
    arrDat = Union(CriteriaRange, DataRange)

    For i = LBound(arrDat, 1) To UBound(arrDat, 1)
        If arrDat(i, 1) = Criteria1 Or arrDat(i, 1) = Criteria2 Then
            If UBound(arrRes) = 0 Then
                ReDim arrRes(1 To 1)
                arrRes(1) = arrDat(i, 2)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To UBound(arrRes) + 1)
                arrRes(UBound(arrRes)) = arrDat(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    SMALLIF = arrRes(1)
    For i = LBound(arrRes) To UBound(arrRes)
        If arrRes(i) < SMALLIF Then
            SMALLIF = arrRes(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

So it should look something like this:

[image: VB editor with code]

Now you can close the VB editor and you can write the following in a cell:

```
=SMALLIF("WCON"; "ACK"; 'Raw PM Data'!$E$2:$E$999; 'Raw PM Data'!$L$2:$L$999)
```

This should now return the earliest date for the work orders with states WCON and ACK.

(keep in mind that your Excel might use `,` as argument separators while mine uses `;` argument separators